# What is the purpose to add padding to hex?

Tags: java, encryption, hex

Hi I read [this post](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#javasourcecode) on how to implement salt and hashing to the password and I am stuck on specified code underneath the website I specified above.

```
private static String toHex(byte[] array)
{
    BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(1, array);
    String hex = bi.toString(16);
    int paddingLength = (array.length * 2) - hex.length();
    if(paddingLength > 0)
        return String.format("%0" + paddingLength + "d", 0) + hex;
    else
        return hex;
}
```

My question is that why did they calculate the `paddingLength` and implement it to the hex if the result `paddingLength` is greater than zero?

Answer (score 2):

`BigInteger(byte[])` interprets the byte array into a two's complement value; this means that it has 2^(8*N) possible values for an N-length array (since each byte contains 8 bits).

Meanwhile, a hex string of length M has 16^M possible values (since each character encodes one of 16 values).

The authors want a one-to-one mapping between the `byte[]` and the `String`: given a String, you should be able to exactly determine the `byte[]` it came from. To get that, we have to make sure the string can encode exactly as many values as the `byte[]`. Plugging in the numbers from above, we get:

```
(# values for an N-length byte[]) == (# values for an M-length String)
2^(8*N)                           == 16^M
```

Let's solve for M in terms of N. The first step is to re-write that right-hand side. If you remember your [exponent power rules](http://www.rapidtables.com/math/number/exponent.htm#power), a^(b*c) == (a^b)^c. Let's get the base of the exponent on the right to be a 2:

```
                                  == (2^4)^M
                                  == 2^(4*M)
```

So we have 2^(8*N) == 2^(4*M).  If 2^k == 2^j, that means k == j. So, 8*N == 4*M. Dividing both sides by 4 yields M = 2N.

To tie it back together, remember that N was the length of the byte array, and M was the length of the hex string. We've just figured out that for there to be a one-to-one mapping, M = 2N -- in other words, the hex string should be twice as long as the byte array.

The padding ensures that.

Comment: That's of course a correct answer, but the `toHex()` method above should not be used. It is slow, hard to read, uses additional memory, uses a format string with dynamic contects, etc. etc.

Comment: True. I was focusing on the intent (doubling the length of the byte array) rather than the implementation, since that's what the question seemed to be about.

Answer (score 1):

Because they wanted all the bytes in the array to be represented in the hex string, even if they are leading zero bytes.

It is not the most obvious way to write a `toHex` method though.

I find something like this much clearer:

```
private static String toHex(byte[] array) {
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    for (byte b : array) {
        s.append(String.format("%02x", b));
    }
    return s.toString();
}
```

Comment: That's my method as well (if I don't require performance). I do however always specify `array.length * 2` in the constructor of the string builder.